# Send filebeat output to multiple Logstash servers without load balancing

Tags: logstash, hosts, elastic-stack, graylog, filebeat

I am trying to send the same logs from Filebeat to two different servers (one Logstash and one Graylog server) without load balancing. We are testing ELK and Graylog at our company and for testing purposes, we'd like to send the logs to two different stacks. However, on the *filebeat.yml* file, I only see an option to give a list of logstash servers if one wants to load balance. Otherwise the default is false so all the logs will only go to one server chosen at random.
This is what I have in the yml file:

```
### Logstash as output
logstash:
# The Logstash hosts
hosts: ["logstash-host:5044"]

# Number of workers per Logstash host.
#worker: 1

# Set gzip compression level.
#compression_level: 3

# Optional load balance the events between the Logstash hosts
#loadbalance: true
```

If I change it to:

```
### Logstash as output
logstash:
# The Logstash hosts
hosts: ["logstash-host:5044", "graylog-host:5044"]

# Number of workers per Logstash host.
#worker: 1

# Set gzip compression level.
#compression_level: 3

# Optional load balance the events between the Logstash hosts
#loadbalance: true
```

I will only get the logs sent to one of these.

And if I set **loadbalance: true**, the logs get distributed to two of the servers. Is there a way to send **all** logs to **both** the servers?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after some research, it looks like the same yml file cannot be used for such purposes for now: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/1035

However, a way around this is to create another service (for Windows) or another console (in Linux) with two different .yml files, each with a different logstash output.

Comment: The question is how filebeat knows that we're sending to greylog, not to logstash (we specified logstash in config). It doesn't even know about greylog...

Comment: You can set up a system such that Filebeat can send logs to Logstash which can then filter it if necessary and send it to Graylog.